# I'm trying create a safety rating for an application i'm working on but i'm new and lost

Tags: php

I'm trying create a safety rating for an application i'm working on but i cant figure out how to get three separate variable to compare to one variable, i'm not really good at coding but and this is all i can come up with but it doesn't work, it just disregards everything and only prints "this area is safe" regardless of the variables present:

```
if ('AssaultSafe' > 131) {
            print("This area is not safe");
    }else if ('AssaultSafe' < 69){
            print("This area is safe");
    }
    if else (print("This ares is neutral"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, `if else (print("This ares is neutral"));` should give you an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting '(' in ...

Your code is comparing a string `AssaultSafe` to integers, which results in the string being converted to an integer. The integer value of `AssaultSafe` is 0, so your second `else if` is hit, resulting in "*This area is safe*".

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

---

Assuming you have a *variable* called `$AssaultSafe` somewhere, your code should be:

```
$AssaultSafe = 132;
if ($AssaultSafe > 131) {
  print("This area is not safe");
} else if ($AssaultSafe < 69){
  print("This area is safe");
} else {
  print("This area is neutral");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case switch statement being more better solution:

```
$neutralBorder = 69;
$dangerBorder = 131;

$score = (int) `your value`;
switch (true) {
    case $score < $neutralBorder:
        print("This area is neutral");
        break;
     case $score >= $neutralBorder && $score <= $dangerBorder:
        print("This area is safe");
        break;
     case $score > $dangerBorder:
        print("This area is not safe");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Why would `switch` be better suited? Any specific reason? Speed?

Comment: also backticks in php are `shell_exec`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, i think it`s risky usage that function for newbie